# Shortcuts on my desktop?

Tags: permissions, menu, context-menu

I'm new to Ubuntu. I have 14.04 release, and I wanted to add a shortcut of /var/www to my desktop, since I want to do some PHP development.
I went to /var/www to make a link, but my right-click menu is greyed out:
[image: right click grey]

Why is that and how do I solve it?

Comment: If you run nautilus with sudo (`sudo nautilus`) then you will able to click on "Make Link" button in whole file system (`/`).

Comment: @Pandya [`gksudo nautilus` or `sudo -H nautilus` or `sudo -i nautilus` are preferable to `sudo nautilus`.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-user-should-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ln -s /var/www/ ~/Desktop/www
```

You can replace the "www" after Desktop with anything you like.

Answer (score 3):

"Make link" option is greyed out because the directory is outside your home directory, and you need superuser privileges to create files there. The simplest solution is to create a symbolic link manually. Open a terminal and type

```
ln -s <file> <link>
```

Replace `<file>` and `<link>` with proper filenames. `<link>` should be inside your home directory.